# Работа с памятью на Cи

Tags: c

Дорогое комьюнити.

Я не понимаю, что отнимает память в количестве байтов строки `char *key`.

Тестил при помощи `valgrind`.

```
int main(){
        char *key = calloc(20, sizeof(char));
        printf("Enter word: \n");
        printf("Enter key: \n");
        scanf("%s", key);
         printf("Key before: %s\n", key);
        set_up_key(&key);

        printf("Key: %s\n", key);
        free(key);
    }
    void set_up_key(char **key){
        size_t size_key = strlen(*key);
        char *buffer = calloc(size_key, sizeof(char));
        buffer = *key;
        char arr_l[25] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz";
        char arr_ll[25] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ";
        char *arr_fl = malloc(size_key);
        for(int i = 0; i < size_key; i++){
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 25; i2++){
                if(buffer[i] == arr_l[i2] || buffer[i] == arr_ll[i2]){
                    arr_fl[i] = arr_l[i2];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        *key = arr_fl;
        free(buffer);
        free(arr_fl);

    }
```

При вводе в `char *key` значения 'A' valgrind пишет:

    `LEAK SUMMARY:
     ==338==    definitely lost: 1 bytes in 1 blocks
     ==338==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     ==338==    possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     ==338==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
     ==338==    suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks`

Пожалуйста, помогите :)

Comment: Ваша программа выводит у меня случайный мусор при одной и той же входной строке.

Comment: Начать можно с того, что: 1) память, выделенная вторым calloc, никак не используется (вы выкидываете указатель на неё в следующей строчке, заменяя его на указатель из `*key`), и это очевидная утечка памяти; 2) вы помещаете указатель `arr_fl` в `key`, но через строку освобождаете его `free(arr_fl)`, и у вас внутри `key` в итоге висячий указатель, указывающий в никуда; 3) в строке `free(key)` вы освобождаете его ВТОРОЙ раз, потому что ранее вы освободили его строкой `free(arr_fl)`

Comment: У вас указатель char *key получает другой адрес в ф-ции set_up_key(). Изначальный адрес таким образом теряется и заключительное free() делает неизвестно что. В общем, все криво.

Comment: Похоже, вы искренне считаете, что тут - `buffer = *key;` - копируется не указатель, а содержимое строки `*key` в строку `buffer`. Но это не так. Для этого нужно использовать `strcpy()`.

Comment: 25 - мало. В строке же ещё 0 есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в строке `*key = arr_fl;` затираете старое значение указателя новым, а значит никогда не освободите память, на которую он указывал. Подозреваю, вам нужно заменить эту строку на использование `memcpy`.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, сделал как вы сказали и заработало.
Также поменял `buffer = *key`, на `strcpy(buffer, *key)`.